# How can we have dynamic xml element name in C# class file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

This is my current XML Response tag

```
<Response_Data_1234 diffgr:id="Response_Data_1234" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<Status>File received.</Status>
<Time>2022-01-25T09:44:15.73+08:00</Time>
<Location>HKG</Location>
</Response_Data_1234>
```

the number 1234 in <Response_Data_1234> is a Response Data id, which will be dynamic depending on the request.
Could someone please me create a C# class in this scenario so that I can map the response directly to the class. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Response_Data_1234` should be a class. Unless you really plan on making a non standard xml then you have 2 choices. Write custom converters or easier write your own xml generator as it does not follow any standard. Anyhow you will have to write a reader as it wont be readable by default

Comment: @franck : how can we make Response_Data_1234 as class ..because i guess 1234 is dynamic base on the current id.

Comment: @AbhijeetChoudhari if it's really dynamic then he is not using a standard XML format and he simply invented one. Therefore there is nothing that exist that is made to save or load that and has to be coded manually.

Comment: Why do you want to use this? If you have a choice restrict yourself to standard XML. Then the XMLDocument class will be very helpful in reading data you need. Can you post the code of your own attempts to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually you should not have any unique identifier attached to XML element name. It should be added as attribute.**

To answer your question:
There is no direct class attribute to ignore class name while deserialisation of xml string to object.

**Option1** (better): Create mapper extension method for XNode to class attribute mapping and reuse it.

**Option2**:
If your xml string is small you can try to update name of root element and use it to deserialise.

sample code:

```
    var responseDataXDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    responseDataXDoc.Root.Name = "ResponseData";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseData));
    var responseData = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseDataXDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)));
```